# Remove sku number from order email - magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I am completely new to magento & using version 1.7. I want to remove sku number from the order email when customer place an order. After lot of R&D I noticed that, the template used is from  `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml` and product name, sku number, quantity and price comes from `echo $this->getItemHtml($_item)` this line. I am not exactly figure out, how should I remove sku number column from this single line? 
Or is there any other way to do so?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me explain you all process.

you can find order email template at app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html.
In this file you can find this line `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}` at Line no. 97

In this you can see handle is "sales_email_order_items" you can find this block in app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\sales.xml line no. 268.

```
<sales_email_order_items>
<block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
    <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
        <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
        <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
        <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
            <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
        </block>
    </block>
</block>
<block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
```

In this block you can see the file path "email/order/items.phtml (app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items.phtml)"

In this file just comment this code 
`<th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>` at line no. 33

And now on above block you can see another file path 'email\order\items\order\default.phtml(app\design\frontend\base\default\template\email\order\items\order\default.phtml)'

In this file just comment this code `<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px; border-bottom:1px dotted #CCCCCC;"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getSku($_item)) ?></td>` at line no. 48.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.3 the "sales_email_order_renderers.xml" render the phtml.file which define the content for the items in the order email.

To remove the SKU, you can do the following steps:

- create module (e.g. COMPANY/SAMPLE)
- copy the "sales_email_order_renders.xml" from /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/  to /app/code/COMPANY/SAMPLE/view/frontend/layout/
- copy the "default.phtml" from /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/  to /app/code/COMPANY/SAMPLE/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/
- update the "sales_email_order_renders.xml" in your module to render the "default.phtml" in your module (see following example)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
          <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items\Order\DefaultOrder" name="sales.email.order.renderers.default" as="default" 
                  template="COMPANY_SAMPLE::email/items/order/default.phtml"/>
      </referenceBlock>
  </body>
  ```

  - Remove the SKU from the default.phtml
  - clear cache (php bin/magento cache:flush)